# SQL - Get rows from all tables where a common column is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, information-schema

I need to find all of the rows in any table where the create/update date are null

There are over 500 tables so doing something like the following is not feasible.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         'tableA' AS `table`,
         IF(COUNT(`column_a`), NULL, 'column_a') AS `column`
     FROM tableA

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 
         'tableB' AS `table`,
         IF(COUNT(`column_b`), NULL, 'column_b') AS `column`
     FROM tableB

     UNION ALL
     -- etc.
     ) t 
WHERE 
    `column` IS NOT NULL
```

I figured I could use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` somehow but I am having difficulty with that.

Comment: So you have a bunch of tables that all have Create_Date and Update_Date as columns? Then you need all the information for each row in each table where either of those dates are NULL?

Comment: This is tagged sql-server but the code looks suspiciously like mysql.

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` (or the `sys.tables`, `sys.columns` etc. catalog views) gives you information about the (static) **structure** of your database - table names, column names etc. - but *not* about the contents (values - `NULL` or not)

Comment: Yes, you can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` as a step for achieving what you need. Write a stored procedure where you execute a query for every table or build one query.

Comment: SQL Server has a sp_MSforeachtable function that works great for this. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16977.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I generally do this by using sys.tables to populate a list of the tables into a temp table, then compose dynamic SQL around that list.

```
select quotename( schemas.name ) + '.' + quotename(tables.name) as tbl
into #work 
from sys.tables
join sys.schemas on tables.schema_id = schemas.schema_id

select 

'select ''' + tbl + ''' as [table] where exists ( select * from ' + tbl + ' where column_a is null )' as sqlcmd,

'select ''' + tbl + ''' as [table], * from ' + tbl + ' where createdate is null ' as sqlcmd

from #work

drop table #work
```

Once you have the list you can execute it manually in SSMS or iterate through it using a cursor to execut each statement. The quotation marks can give you a headache, though. Dynamic SQL isn't for the faint of heart.